# Codeigniter active record with several like or?

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter, mysql

Hey.. I've run into a problem using several "like" in my sql-query (generated with Codeigniter's activerecord):

```
SELECT * FROM (`posts`) WHERE `city` LIKE '%test%' AND `title` LIKE '%%' OR `text` LIKE '%%'
```

Thing is, it appears to read this query as if there was a parenthesis around the first like and the second like, but I want there to be a parenthesis around the second and the last like (I want it to compare if the last or the next to last works).

How can I achieve this using Codeigniter's Active Record class?

Current code:
        if($type != 0)
        $this->db->where('type', $type);

```
    $this->db->like('city', $area);
    $this->db->like('title', $words);
    $this->db->or_like('text', $words);

    return $this->db->get('posts')->result_array();
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't do that, so you could stick to vanilla sql in this case.

Comment: Enable the profileR which will show you exactly what queries are being run just to check that what you think is happening is actually happening! Do this by putting this before you output anything: $this->output->enable_profiler(true);

Comment: In the CI 3.0-dev you can add groups in query: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25702839/1102037

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think CI is adding any paranthesis. It will add an 'AND' between the first two statements and an 'OR' between the last two. To achieve what you want, I would write my own statement. It's very straightforward.

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM 'posts' WHERE city LIKE ? AND ( title LIKE ? OR text LIKE ? );
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($area, $words, $words));
```

Notice how I've used binding. This automatically escapes characters for you.

Comment: Ok, thx this will solve my problem. You are right, I don't think I can add parenthesis with Codeigniter's active record.

Answer (score 20):

Previous answer is correct. I would like to add the following...

In Codeigniter supporting the following overall...

```
$this->db->like();
$this->db->or_like();
$this->db->not_like();
$this->db->or_not_like();
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 4):

this will do the trick

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('my_table')
        ->group_start()
                ->where('a', 'a')
                ->or_group_start()
                        ->where('b', 'b')
                        ->where('c', 'c')
                ->group_end()
        ->group_end()
        ->where('d', 'd')
->get();

// Generates:
// SELECT * FROM (`my_table`) WHERE ( `a` = 'a' OR ( `b` = 'b' AND `c` = 'c' ) ) AND `d` = 'd'
```

Answer (score 0):

when you have to use table join as well try following method

```
public function get_all_airports($para) {

        $this->db->select('airports.name as air_name, airports.city, airports.type, airports.home_link, country.name as con_name');
        $this->db->from('airports');

        $this->db->join('country', 'airports.iso_country = country.code', 'inner');

        $this->db->where("airports.type !=", "small_airport");
        $this->db->where("airports.type !=", "closed");
        $this->db->where("airports.type !=", "heliport");
        $this->db->where("airports.type !=", "medium_airport");
        $this->db->where("airports.type !=", "seaplane_base");

        $where = "(country.name LIKE '%$para%' OR airports.city LIKE '%$para%')";
        $this->db->where($where);

        echo json_encode($this->db->limit(20)->get()->result());
    }
```