# Codeigniter parentheses in dynamic Active Record query

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm producing a query like the following using ActiveRecord

```
SELECT * FROM (`foods`) WHERE `type` = 'fruits' AND 
       `tags` LIKE '%green%' OR `tags` LIKE '%blue%' OR `tags` LIKE '%red%'
```

The number of `tags` and values is unknown. Arrays are created dynamically. Below I added a possible array.

```
$tags = array (                 
        '0'     => 'green'.
        '1'     => 'blue',
        '2'     => 'red'
);
```

Having an array of tags, I use the following loop to create the query I posted on top.

```
$this->db->where('type', $type); //var type is retrieved from input value

foreach($tags as $tag):         
     $this->db->or_like('tags', $tag);
endforeach;
```

The issue: I need to add parentheses around the `LIKE` clauses like below:

```
SELECT * FROM (`foods`) WHERE `type` = 'fruits' AND 
      (`tags` LIKE '%green%' OR `tags` LIKE '%blue%' OR `tags` LIKE '%red%')
```

I know how to accomplish this if the content within the parentheses was static but the foreach loop throws me off..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the CI wiki:

> The codeignighter ActiveRecord feature
>   allows you to create SQL queries
>   relatively simply and
>   database-independant, however there
>   isno specific support for including
>   parenthesis in an SQL query.

For example when you want a where statement to come out simmilarly to the folowing:

```
WHERE (field1 = value || field2 = value) AND (field3 = value2 || field4 = value2)
```

This can be worked around by feeding a string to the CI->db->where() function, in this case you will want to specifically escape your values.

See the following example:

```
$value=$this->db->escape($value);
$value2=$this->db->escape($value2);
$this->db->from('sometable');
$this->db->where("($field = $value || $field2 = $value)");
$this->db->where("($field3 = $value2 || $field4 = $value2)");
$this->db->get();
```

A simmilar workaround can be used for LIKE clauses:

```
$this->db->where("($field LIKE '%$value%' || $field2 LIKE '%$value%')");
$this->db->where("($field3 LIKE '%$value2%' || $field4 LIKE '%$value2%')");
```

Comment: Thanks @The Silencer, that is good information. Using your example I edited my loop like so, `foreach($tags as $tag): $this->db->where("($field LIKE '%$tag%')"); endforeach; ` which gives me this sort of query `SELECT * FROM ('foods') WHERE 'type' = 'fruits' AND (tags LIKE '%green%') AND (tags LIKE '%red%') AND (tags LIKE '%blue%')`  Is it ok for every `LIKE` clause to be in separate  parentheses? I can't put all clauses in one query like in your example, because mine are created dynamic.

Comment: Note for anyone trying to achieve this: for escaping `LIKE` clauses codeigniter uses `$this->db->escape_like_str($value)`otherwise it adds single quotes inside the wildcards.

Comment: THANK YOU for this - I'm never using CI again after the 3 hours this has just put me though!

Comment: I've used DB abstractions from several frameworks like CI, Yii, Zend, AdoDB etc.. Laravel really beats them all in simplicity and readability. Check it out if you haven't done so already! And you don't have to use the whole laravel framework if you don't want to, just use the DB package.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for. It worked like a charm, cheers!!!

Answer (score 26):

In the CI 3.0-dev you can add groups in query:

```
$this->db->select('id, title')
->group_start()
->or_like([ 'title' => $s, 'id' => $s ])
->group_end()                
->where([ 'b_del' => 0 ]);
```

Produces:

```
SELECT `id`, `title`, `venda1`
FROM `itens`
WHERE   
(
`title` LIKE '%a%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `id` LIKE '%a%' ESCAPE '!'
 )
AND `b_del` =0
```

Answer (score 8):

One of best feature to save your query when you applying multiple where or_where clauses.

```
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->where();
$this->db->or_where();
$this->db->group_end();
```

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: For some reason CI was adding an extra quote around my first where when I included parentheses: something like "age > 5 and state ='MN'". Then I needed to add an extra where (with AND). So, needed parentheses. This solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Going off of The Silencer's solution, I wrote a tiny function to help build like conditions

```
function make_like_conditions (array $fields, $query) {
    $likes = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $likes[] = "$field LIKE '%$query%'";
    }
    return '('.implode(' || ', $likes).')';
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
$search_fields = array(
    'field_1',
    'field_2',
    'field_3',
);
$query = "banana"
$like_conditions = make_like_conditions($search_fields, $query);
$this->db->from('sometable')
    ->where('field_0', 'foo')
    ->where($like_conditions)
    ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my successful solution:

```
$this->db->where("(table.field = $variable OR table.field IS NULL)");
```

Answer (score 0):

use codeigniter 3

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->MasterMember);
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where($this->IDCardStatus, '1');
    $this->db->or_where($this->IDCardStatus, '2');
    $this->db->group_end();

    if ($searchKey1 != null) {
        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->like($this->MemberID, $searchKey1);
        $this->db->or_like($this->FirstName, $searchKey2);
        $this->db->or_like($this->LastName, $searchKey3);
        $this->db->group_end();
    }

    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);


    $data = $this->db->get();
```

this is my native query

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    `Member` 
WHERE ( `Member`.`IDCardStatus` = '1' OR `Member`.`IDCardStatus` = '2' ) 
AND ( `Member`.`MemberID` LIKE '%some_key%' ESCAPE '!' OR `Member`.`FirstName` LIKE '%some_key%' ESCAPE '!' OR `Member`.`LastName` LIKE '%some_key%' ESCAPE '!' ) 
    LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for codeigniter 4:

```
$builder->select('*')->from('my_table')
        ->groupStart()
            ->where('a', 'a')
            ->orGroupStart()
                    ->where('b', 'b')
                    ->where('c', 'c')
            ->groupEnd()
    ->groupEnd()
    ->where('d', 'd')
->get();

// Generates:
// SELECT * FROM (`my_table`) WHERE ( `a` = 'a' OR ( `b` = 'b' AND `c` = 'c' ) ) AND `d` = 'd'
```

from official docs on: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Answer (score -1):

```
$likes = array (                 
    '0'     => 'green'.
    '1'     => 'blue',
    '2'     => 'red'
);  
$where_like = "("; 
$or_counter = 1;
foreach($likes as $like_key => $like_val):
    $or_content = ($or_counter > 1) ?'OR': '';
    $newlikeval = $this->db->escape_like_str($like_val);
    $where_like .= $or_content." `$like_key` LIKE  '%$newlikeval%' ";
    $or_counter++;
endforeach;
$where_like .= ")";
$this->db->where($where_like);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't add parentheses in ActiveRecord, but maybe WHERE IN is what you're looking for?

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
// Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

Comment: This is not the same thing at all. Most likely it is a search feature and needs the `LIKE` and wildcards.