# WHERE OR stops LIKE from working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have this query being generated by codeignter:

```
SELECT `games_link`.`APPID`, `games_other`.`name`, `games_other`.`logo`, `platforms`.`PID`, `platforms`.`name` AS pname, `platforms`.`logo` AS plogo 
FROM (`games_link`) 
LEFT JOIN `games_platforms` ON `games_platforms`.`APPID` = `games_link`.`APPID`
LEFT JOIN `platforms` ON `platforms`.`PID` = `games_platforms`.`PID` 
LEFT JOIN `games_other` ON `games_other`.`APPID` = `games_link`.`GB_ID` 
WHERE `games_platforms`.`PID` = '94' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '139' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '35' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '129' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '146' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '20' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '145' 
AND `games_other`.`name` LIKE '%knack%' LIMIT 15
```

[image]

When this runs it does not filter via the LIKE, it just returns everything, But if I run this:

```
SELECT `games_link`.`APPID`, `games_other`.`name`, `games_other`.`logo`, `platforms`.`PID`, `platforms`.`name` AS pname, `platforms`.`logo` AS plogo 
FROM (`games_link`) 
LEFT JOIN `games_platforms` ON `games_platforms`.`APPID` = `games_link`.`APPID` 
LEFT JOIN `platforms` ON `platforms`.`PID` = `games_platforms`.`PID` 
LEFT JOIN `games_other` ON `games_other`.`APPID` = `games_link`.`GB_ID` 
WHERE `games_other`.`name` LIKE '%knack%' LIMIT 15
```

It runs the LIKE.
[image]

Comment: You might want to consider reading these [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552821/codeigniter-parentheses-in-dynamic-active-record-query) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470267/grouping-where-clauses-in-codeigniter).

Comment: Use braces in your query `( cond1 or cond2 or cond3) and cond4`. Is it possible in your system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you intend for any of the game types to be combined with the `and`.  However, your logic is incorrect because you have no parentheses.  The easiest way to fix it is to use `in`:

```
WHERE `games_platforms`.`PID` in (94, 139, 35, 129, 146, 146, 20, 145) and
      `games_other`.`name` LIKE '%knack%' ;
```

In the future, use parentheses around conditions in the `where` clause until you fully understand the precedence rules for `or` and `and`.

Comment: This is being generated by codeignters active record. So cant really avoid stuff like this easily.

Comment: Have you seen the comment of Maxime Morin to your original post? I think this would help you.

Comment: I already fixed it before that with: ->where('games_platforms.PID IN (94,'.implode(",", $plat).')')

Answer (score 0):

Since you say it is not possible to generate query in `in clause` as suggested by Gordon Linoff, Try if this is possible:

```
WHERE 
( -----> Open paranthesis here
`games_platforms`.`PID` = '94' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '139' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '35' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '129' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '146' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '20' 
OR `games_platforms`.`PID` = '145' 
) -----> Close paranthesis here
AND `games_other`.`name` LIKE '%knack%' LIMIT 15
```