# Codeigniter where statement with parenthesis

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, where-clause

What i'm traying to do is to set into the where statement a parenthesis. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    `a_id`
FROM
    `auctions`
WHERE
    `a_state` = 1
AND (
    `p_name` LIKE '%XXX%'
    OR `at_name` LIKE '%XXX%'
    OR `p_code` LIKE '%XXX%'
)
```

But i don't want to do it with

```
$this->db->query('SELECT  `a_id` FROM `auctions` WHERE  `a_state` =1 AND (`p_name` LIKE  '%XXX%' OR `at_name` LIKE  '%XXX%' OR  `p_code` LIKE  '%XXX%');
```

I want to use the active record class.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Never mind, where i found the answer.
[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552821/codeigniter-parentheses-in-dynamic-active-record-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$where="`a_state` =1 AND (`p_name` LIKE  '%XXX%' OR `at_name` LIKE  '%XXX%' OR  `p_code` LIKE  '%XXX%')";

    $this->db->select('a_id');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->from('auctions');
    $query = $this->db->get('');
echo  $this->db->last_query();// print the last query
```