# How to escape parameter in like sql query using active record?

Tags: sql, activerecord, codeigniter-3

Have query with parentesis:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE company_id = 1 AND (
    name LIKE "%smith%" OR 
    last_name LIKE "%smith%"
)
```

But in codeigniter have:

```
$query_members = $this->db
    ->select('users.*')
    ->from('users')
    ->like(array('users.names' => $search))
    ->or_like(array('users.last_name' => $search))
    ->where(array('users.company_id' => 1));
```

This generate:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE 
    name LIKE '%smith%' OR 
    last_name LIKE '%smith%' AND 
    company_id = 1;
```

And does not works, i need ((a or b) and c), not (a or b and c). I found solution here: [Codeigniter parentheses in dynamic Active Record query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552821/codeigniter-parentheses-in-dynamic-active-record-query) but the variable is escaped with full quotes, i need escape with "%" pre and pos value. I have this:

```
$search_escaped = $this->db->escape($search);
$query_members = $this->db
    ->select('users.*')
    ->from('users')
    ->where('(users.names LIKE "%'.$search_escaped.'%" OR users.last_name LIKE "%'.$search_escaped.'%")')
    ->where(array('members.company_id' => (int)$company_id));
```

But the query add bad quotes:

```
SELECT `users`.*
FROM `users`
WHERE (users.names LIKE "%'smith'%" OR users.last_name LIKE "%'smith'%")
AND `members`.`company_id` = 2
```

The "%'smith'%" is bad quoted. How I can solve this by using active record of codeigniter 3.0.0?

Comment: so essentially you now have the correct syntax but with quotes?. The docs do mention a third paramter in the where method to turn off back-ticks. "$this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks." https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#chaining

Comment: It would be ->where('query ...', null, false) ? I'll try...

Comment: Looks like it. I have never actually used it though but it looks promising

Comment: @WHK Sounds like you managed to find the solution within your comments?