# How to a combination of get_where and like in CI?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, model

I create a model in CI "get_where" and I what to combinate with "like" this is my code

```
$where = array();

    if ($courses != '') $where['courses'] = $courses;
    if ($session != '') $where['session'] = $session;

    if ($datefrom != '') $where['date >='] = $datefrom;
    if ($dateto != '') $where['date <='] = $dateto;
    if ($timefrom != '') $where['in_time >='] = $timefrom;
    if ($timeto != '') $where['in_time <='] = $timeto;

    if (empty($where))
    {
    return array(); // ... or NULL
    }
    else
    {

        if($order != ''){
            $this->db->order_by($order);
        }else{
            $this->db->order_by("date", "DESC");
        }

        $getQuery = $this->db->get_where('absent', $where);
        return $query = $getQuery->result();
    }

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
```

When I add like `$this->db->like('name',$name);` before `$getQuery` the result is always empty.

How to a combination of get_where and like in CI?

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489399/codeigniter-active-record-with-several-like-or

Comment: thanks let me check..